# two component gaussian fit not working correctly

Tags: python, numpy, plot, curve-fitting, gaussian

I am trying to do a two component gaussian fit with the following code:

```
def double_gaussian(velo_peak,a1, mu1, sigma1, a2, mu2, sigma2):
                      
            
            res_two = a1 * np.exp(-(velo_peak - mu1)**2/(2 * sigma1**2))  \
                      + a2 * np.exp(-(velo_peak - mu2)**2/(2 * sigma2**2))

            return res_two
#Guess parameters:
guess = [5, 115.2, 0.7, 4, 115.7, 0.7]
popt,pcov = curve_fit(double_gaussian, velo_peak, spec_peak, guess)
plt.plot(velo_peak*1e-9, double_gaussian(velo_peak, *popt), 'r-', label='fit')
```

i defined the equation with two components, then put the guess values and tried to plot, but I'm obtaining the following error:
`warnings.warn('Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated',`
And thus I'm getting a straight line for the fit.
I would say I find the code logical, but of course, there is something wrong. Any help provided would be much appreciated .
[image]

Comment: Why are you doing this `velo_peak*1e-9`? Also, what is inside `velo/spec_peak`, can you provide sample data?

Comment: it is huge sample data I thought it won't be useful as they can be considered as two arrays with values. velo_peak was multiplied by this factor just for the sake of conversions.

Comment: I tried your code on sample data that I generated as they do in the example [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) and it worked without issues, without the `*1e-9`.

Comment: How sure you are of the initial guess? I'm fitting the data with increasingly worse guesses, and at a certain point I get the warning, and the fit fails. Maybe upload a small random sample on pastebin or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in the initial guess:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # type: ignore
import numpy as np  # type: ignore
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit  # type: ignore

def double_gaussian(velo_peak, a1, mu1, sigma1, a2, mu2, sigma2):
    g1 = a1 * np.exp(-((velo_peak - mu1) ** 2) / (2 * sigma1 ** 2))
    g2 = a2 * np.exp(-((velo_peak - mu2) ** 2) / (2 * sigma2 ** 2))
    return g1 + g2

xdata = np.linspace(100, 120, 1000)
y = double_gaussian(xdata, 5, 115.2, 0.7, 4, 105.7, 0.7)
np.random.seed(1729)
y_noise = 0.2 * np.random.normal(size=xdata.size)
ydata = y + y_noise
plt.plot(xdata, ydata, "b-", label="data")

# Guess parameters:
# guess = [5, 115.2, 0.7, 4, 105.7, 0.7]  # ok (duh)
# guess = [1, 100, 1, 1, 100, 1]  # fails 10k
# guess = [5, 100, 1, 4, 100, 1]  # fails 10k
# guess = [5, 115, 1, 4, 105, 1]  # ok
# guess = [5, 115, 5, 4, 105, 5]  # warn
# guess = [5, 115, 2, 4, 105, 2]  # ok
# guess = [1, 115, 2, 1, 105, 2]  # ok
# guess = [1, 115, 3, 1, 105, 3]  # ok
# guess = [1, 110, 3, 1, 110, 3]  # ok
# guess = [1, 100, 3, 1, 120, 3]  # only one found
# guess = [1, 120, 3, 1, 100, 3]  # only one found
guess = [1, 118, 3, 1, 102, 3]  # ok
popt, pcov = curve_fit(double_gaussian, xdata, ydata, guess, maxfev=10000)
plt.plot(xdata, double_gaussian(xdata, *popt), "r-", label="fit")

plt.show()
```

Without access to the data it is hard to help. You might want to try some way to find the peak locations, and use that as `mu1/2` value, it could help. Or some kind of grid search on the starting parameter space, evaluated on the error between model and data.

**Edit**:

I tried increasing the number of iteration for the optimizer call `maxfev=100_000_000`, and got these results:

```
# guess = [1, 100, 1, 1, 100, 1]  # bad 100kk
# guess = [1, 118, 1, 1, 102, 1]  # ok 100kk
# guess = [1, 110, 1, 1, 110, 1]  # bad 100kk
# guess = [1, 111, 1, 1, 109, 1]  # bad 100kk
guess = [1, 112, 1, 1, 108, 1]  # ok 100kk
```

So again, the starting `mu` values seems very important.

Cheers!